# Resolve reference in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm trying to resolve an id/idref reference in xslt.
Unfortunately, no data is displayed... am I doing something wrong?

Since I defined `projektId`as type `ID` I should be able to use the `id(...)`-function or am I wrong?

---

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Projekt.xsl"?>
<school xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="Projekt.xsd">
    <personen>
        <person id="1">
            <name>a</name>
            <kuerzel>a</kuerzel>
            <email>a@a.ch</email>
            <projektRef projektIdRef="p1" />
        </person>
        <person id="2">
            <name>b</name>
            <kuerzel>b</kuerzel>
            <email>b@b.ch</email>
            <projektRef projektIdRef="p1" />
        </person>
        <person id="3">
            <name>c</name>
            <kuerzel>c</kuerzel>
            <email>c@c.ch</email>
            <projektRef projektIdRef="p2" />
        </person>
    </personen>

    <projekte>
        <projekt projektId="p1">
            <name>Projekt 1</name>
        </projekt>
        <projekt projektId="p2">
            <name>Projekt 2</name>
        </projekt>
    </projekte>
</school>
```

## XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="school">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="personen" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="person">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>        
                                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="kuerzel" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="projektRef">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="projektIdRef" type="xs:IDREF" />
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="projekte" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="projekt">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="projektId" type="xs:ID" />
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

## XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:df="http://www.w3schools.com">
<xsl:key name="projectKey" match="df:projekte/projekt" use="@projektId" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>School</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Kürzel</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Email</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Link</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Project</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="df:school/df:personen/df:person">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="df:name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="df:kuerzel"/></td>
        <td><a href="mailto:{df:email}"><xsl:value-of select="df:email" /></a></td>
        <td><img src="http://test.com/portraet/images/{df:kuerzel}.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="id(projekte/@projektId)/name" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also tried to use the following function:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="key('projektKey', @projektId)/name" /></td>
```

but I didn't get any data displayed as well...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which XSLT 1.0 processors (if any) support the `id()` function (and - as Martin Honnen points out - it needs a DTD, not an XSD).

With regard to using a key, you have several syntax errors. Your key should be:

```
<xsl:key name="projectKey" match="df:projekt" use="@projektId" />
```

and you need to call it as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('projectKey', df:projektRef/@projektIdRef)/df:name" />
```

Note also that `df:zhaw` needs to be `df:school`.

Comment: thanks, this worked! :-) good point on the df:school I forgot to change this in the xslt before posting here :)

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 does not have any supported for schema defined types, you would need to define a DTD and make sure you use an XML parser and XSLT processor that support and parse external DTDs (which for instance the XSLT processors in browsers don't (Mozilla) do or only do when requested (IE with MSXML)) to be able to use the `id` function.

As for your attempts to use a schema, the `schemaLocation` attribute takes pairs of `namespace-URI schema-URI`, not a single URI.

And to use a key you need to set it up consistently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:df="http://www.w3schools.com"
  exclude-result-prefixes="df">
<xsl:key name="projectKey" match="df:projekte/df:projekt" use="@projektId" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>School</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Kürzel</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Email</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Link</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Project</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="df:school/df:personen/df:person">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="df:name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="df:kuerzel"/></td>
        <td><a href="mailto:{df:email}"><xsl:value-of select="df:email" /></a></td>
        <td><img src="http://pd.zhaw.ch/portraet/images/{df:kuerzel}.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="key('projectKey', df:projektRef/@projektIdRef)/df:name" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you this worked, when I adjusted the key to `<xsl:key name="projektKey" match="df:projekt" use="@projektId" />` is there a reason, you included `df:projekte` in the key definition?

Comment: Your original code had `match="df:projekte/projekt"` so I corrected the missing prefix `df` in front of `projekt` to have `match="df:projekte/df:projekt"`. With your XML that should work, only having `match="df:projekt"` should suffice as well, however.